# Google closure get value from DOM element

Tags: clojurescript, google-closure-library

I'm using Google closure on top of ClojureScript, what is the way to get a value from a "select" in a html element?

I'm trying :

```
(.value (gdom/getElement "select-combo"))
```

but I'm getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: goog.dom.getElement(...).value is not a function
```

I also tried "getValue" but no luck so far. I can't find the function in Google API docs either.

Using jQuery it should be:

```
   $("#select-combo").val();
```

Comment: Does changing the call to `(.-value ...)` fix it?

Comment: You right! thx!

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the [ClojureScript CheatSheet](http://cljs.info/cheatsheet/)

You can get a value natively

```
(.-innerHTML el)
```

Or using cljs-oops library:

```
(oget el "innerHTML")
```